# System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'FChart'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I download FusionChart and try to use in my MVC4 application. When i tried the same in my application i met an error like this. How to solve this. Any one kindly help me. Thanks for advance.

Error is

```
System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'FChart' and no extension method 'FChart' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Did you add the reference to your project?

Answer (score 1):

You should add HtmlHelper.cs and change namespace as your project name. I am successfully add fusion charts in mvc4.

Please tell me if it is work or not